# User.IsInRole failing after migrating to Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, simplemembership

I have recently updated my MVC 4 application to MVC 5 and Identity 2.0 however I'm having difficulty to get it working. After logging in I get the error "No user found was found that has the name" and entity framework is still creating the old simplemembership tables "webpages_Membership", "webpages_OAuthMembership", "webpages_Roles", and "webpages_UsersInRoles".

I have used the Identity 2.0 methods for adding a new user and role for an admin account and these are showing up in those tables.

So my question is how to I remove any remaining links to simplemembership so that I am only using Identity 2.0. I don't even know where to look to find things to remove.

for reference I am working on visual studio 2012 with the MVC 5 update and tools installed. I have no need to keep existing users so no need to worry about migrating data. Just need help figuring out why it's still using simplememebership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app uses the  `User.IsInRole()` method, add the following to the Web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="RoleManager" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

I came across the same issue, I found the details here (4. At the bottom of the page):

[**How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

Comment: thanks, that worked this time... weirdly i tried it myself earlier this morning as I had come across it too. however it caused a run time error saying my config file was not valid. this time no problems though.. i must have changed something else since then as well.

Comment: @RobertParkinson Nice one. :)